# Insert multiple characters in a string

Tags: sql

Just trying to learn some new skills on sql, I don't know whether this is possible but, I have order numbers as per the below

```
"11074"
"11075"
"11076"
...and so on
```

But I need the output to be:

```
"11-0:7-4"
"11-0:7-5"
"11-0:7-6"
```

However the code I am using only allows me to output "11-076", I cannot find a way to put the ':' or the second '-' in.

```
SELECT
   LEFT(o.orderID,2) + '-' as OrderID_New
FROM
   ORDERS O
```

Is there anyway of using LEFT and RIGHT functions for this or does it need use of other functions?

There is no reason why I am doing this except from learning :)

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, just construct the string.  Assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
select left(o.orderId, 2) + '-' + substring(o.orderId, 3, 1) + ':' + substring(o.orderId, 4, 1) + '-' + right(o.orderId, 1)
```

You could also use the `stuff()` function:

```
select stuff(stuff(stuff(o.orderId, 5, 0, '-'), 4, 0, ':'), 3, 0, '-')
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the substring code errored but the stuff code worked :) first time seeing the stuff function but learnt how to use it :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the substring and concat function.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(orderId,1,2),'-',
  SUBSTRING(orderId,3,1),';',
  SUBSTRING(orderId,4,1),'-',
  SUBSTRING(orderId,5,1)) 
FROM ORDERS;
```